# what will cause a segfault when calling mxCreateDoubleMatrix()?

Tags: c, matlab, valgrind

I'm linking with matlab to write matfiles from within my C code.
When running the following code, i get a segfault (on the first line):

```
pPressure_a = mxCreateDoubleMatrix((MWSIZE)2, (MWSIZE)dim, mxREAL);
if(pPressure_a == NULL){
    fatal("Memory alocation error.");
}
copyDoubleToPtr2D(temp2D_a, mxGetPr(pPressure_a), dim, 2);
matPutVariable(matfile, "p", pPressure_a);
mxDestroyArray(pPressure_a);
```

In the above snippet, "MWSIZE" is #defined as int32_t, as I'm compiling this
with matlab R14, but the #define allows changing this easily for use with
other versions.
Using gdb, I have confirmed that when the first line is called pPressure_a =
0x0; and dim = 501, which are perfectly valid values.

### Here is the backtrace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff73eeb5d in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6

(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff73eeb5d in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff73f103e in malloc () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff7730e35 in ?? () from /usr/local/matlabr14/bin/glnxa64/libut.so
#3  0x00007ffff7731600 in ?? () from /usr/local/matlabr14/bin/glnxa64/libut.so
#4  0x00007ffff7730046 in utCalloc () from /usr/local/matlabr14/bin/glnxa64/libut.so
#5  0x00007ffff7236c76 in mxCreateNumericMatrix () from /usr/local/matlabr14/bin/glnxa64/libmx.so
#6  0x00007ffff7237620 in mxCreateDoubleMatrix () from /usr/local/matlabr14/bin/glnxa64/libmx.so
#7  0x0000000000412c28 in calcCohAcoustPress (settings=0x646ab0) at /home/eey/models/cTraceo/./calcCohAcoustPress.c:324
#8  0x0000000000413736 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe038) at cTraceo.c:137

(gdb) f 7
#7  0x0000000000412c28 in calcCohAcoustPress (settings=0x646ab0) at /home/eey/models/cTraceo/./calcCohAcoustPress.c:324
324            pPressure_a = mxCreateDoubleMatrix((MWSIZE)2, (MWSIZE)dim, mxREAL);
```

---

I'm calling mxCreateDoubleMatrix() in the same way (several times) earlier in the code, and have never had problems.

What can be causing this?

**EDIT**: Running valgrind produces several blocks like this:

```
==17538== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==17538==    at 0x4E560B8: csqrt (s_csqrt.c:66)
==17538==    by 0x40E149: solveDynamicEq (in cTraceo/bin/cTraceo-64b.bin)
==17538==    by 0x411BA5: calcCohAcoustPress (in cTraceo/bin/cTraceo-64b.bin)
==17538==    by 0x413555: main (in cTraceo/bin/cTraceo-64b.bin)
```

And ends with this:

```
Invalid read of size 8
==17538==    at 0x412A3F: calcCohAcoustPress (in cTraceo/bin/cTraceo-64b.bin)
==17538==    by 0x413555: main (in cTraceo/bin/cTraceo-64b.bin)
==17538==  Address 0x86a3050 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd
==17538==    at 0x4C2815C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==17538==    by 0x401781: mallocDouble2D (in cTraceo/bin/cTraceo-64b.bin)
==17538==    by 0x41296D: calcCohAcoustPress (in cTraceo/bin/cTraceo-64b.bin)
==17538==    by 0x413555: main (in cTraceo/bin/cTraceo-64b.bin)
==17538== 
==17538== Invalid write of size 8
==17538==    at 0x412A43: calcCohAcoustPress (in cTraceo/bin/cTraceo-64b.bin)
==17538==    by 0x413555: main (in cTraceo/bin/cTraceo-64b.bin)
==17538==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

==17538== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==17538==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==17538==    at 0x412A43: calcCohAcoustPress (in cTraceo/bin/cTraceo-64b.bin)
==17538==    by 0x413555: main (in cTraceo/bin/cTraceo-64b.bin)
==17538==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==17538==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==17538==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==17538==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==17538==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==17538== Invalid free() / delete / delete[]
==17538==    at 0x4C27D71: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:366)
==17538==    by 0x58FAA0A: free_mem (in /lib/libc-2.12.1.so)
==17538==    by 0x58FA5A1: __libc_freeres (in /lib/libc-2.12.1.so)
==17538==    by 0x4A2366B: _vgnU_freeres (vg_preloaded.c:62)
==17538==    by 0x7FEFFFD27: ???
==17538==    by 0x413555: main (in cTraceo/bin/cTraceo-64b.bin)
==17538==  Address 0x41508a0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Sadly, I'm new to valgrind and don't actually know what that means... :p

Comment: Perhaps some memory-stomping problem has occurred earlier, and corrupted data structures used by `malloc`. If you're on Linux, setting the environment variable `MALLOC_CHECK_` to 3 before running MATLAB may make the C library do extra checks and call `abort` if it spots an inconsistency.

Comment: Try running it in valgrind to see if you're overwriting memory elsewhere.  valgrind ./prog_name

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan: No effect. @DavidMFrey: I'm gonna give it a try.

Comment: You did export the variable to make sure it's present in MATLAB's environment?

Comment: I don't know about R14, but in current MATLAB versions the second argument needs to be a `mwSize*` rather than an `mwSize`. Even if you're actually giving it a pointer, `dim` is going to need two values, one for each dimension.

Comment: @kwatford, current MATLAB documentation on the web says `mxArray *mxCreateDoubleMatrix(mwSize m, mwSize n, mxComplexity ComplexFlag);`; the first argument is the first dimension, not the rank.

Comment: @DavidMFrey: any tips concerning the valgrind output?

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan, ah, sorry, mistook that for `mxCreateDoubleArray`

Comment: I'm not a valgrind expert, but no one who is seems to be commenting here :-) so here's what I think is going on in your valgrind output. (1) The `csqrt` complaints: as it kinda says, it sounds as if you're feeding uninitialized data to `csqrt`. You might want to take a careful look at `solveDynamicEq` and consider making it write out the values it's passing to `csqrt` for human-eyes sanity checking. This doesn't seem very likely to be the cause of the crash, though. [... will continue in next comment]

Comment: (2) The "invalid read of size 8": your code is trying to read past the end of a block of memory (or: is trying to read somewhere a bit random that just happens to be past the end of a block of memory). The address where this is happening seems to be pretty immediately before the code you've posted (0x412A3F versus 0x412A43). You might want to take a look at a few lines of code before the call to `mxCreateDoubleMatrix`. [... will continue in next comment]

Comment: You may be able to identify what the block of memory is that you're reading past the end of, if you combine gdb + valgrind and take a look at the address where it says the memory was allocated. Incidentally, in case you have the same difficulty as I did in parsing valgrind's message about this: it means "You tried to read 8 bytes at 0x86a3050, an address that occurs immediately (0 bytes) after the end of a 16-byte block. Here are (a) the call chain leading to the forbidden memory access and (b) the call chain leading to the allocation of the 16 bytes." [... will continue in next comment]

Comment: Reading 8 bytes probably means either a pointer or a `double`. (3) The invalid write: something attempted to write to address 0 (i.e., through a null pointer). valgrind is reporting the culprit as being in your code; ask `gdb` where; it may not be the same place as for the error you got without valgrind. (Note: for the same reason, I may have been wrong about "immediately before the code you've posted", above.) [... will continue in next comment]

Comment: (4) "Process terminating with default action of signal 11": that's the same invalid write. First valgrind catches it because you're writing to memory your program isn't allowed to write to; then the C runtime catches it because you're actually trying to write to address 0, and that's protected. And then valgrind reports that your program has taken a SIGSEGV and is terminating (because that's the default thing to do when that happens). [... will continue in next comment]

Comment: (5) The invalid-free message: After your program ends, valgrind calls a glibc function called `__libc_freeres` which attempts to free up all the memory it's allocated so that they don't look like memory leaks; unfortunately, this is crashing. That could indicate memory corruption, but it could also be a glibc bug (see http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.exit_errors). Try again with `valgrind --run-libc-freeres=no` to get rid of that particular message.

Comment: (6) A general note: You should save all the valgrind output and (a) look for invalid writes since they are the most likely culprits for your original problem and (b) if you can, fix all the errors it reports (or convince yourself that they're spurious) both to make it easier to spot more serious problems and because any bug may indicate false assumptions that may be causing other problems.

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan: Wow, thanks -that's really detailed help :) I've been going through all the warnings valgrind reports. Most of them (over 100) are actually happening inside shared objects belonging to matlab, so there's nothing i can do about that. As you suggested, right before the call to mxCreateDoubleMatrix() i had a for-loop reading a double more than allocated -fixed it, but that didn't solve the general problem. Hopefully, after revisiting the code and solving everything valgrind reports, this problem will just go away...

Comment: You're welcome. Let me repeat the very important thing I said at the start: I'm not a valgrind expert, and just about any part of what I wrote could turn out to be wrong.

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan, @DavidMFrey: Ok, got i working! I had several cases where (in very rare conditions) I was writing a single position beyond the allocated memory. I suppose at some point I must have written over memory that would later be needed by mxCreateDoubleMatrix(). Valgrind is truly awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the actual crash occurs not at the mxCreateDoubleMatrix() call but rather at the copyDoubleToPtr2D() call? If so, this may be due to the internal [extremely annoying and hard-to-track] limitation of MEX mentioned [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f24626.html#f24851). The solution is to simply use memcpy() rather than copyDoubleToPtr2D().

Answer (score 0):

According to the mxCreateDoubleMatrix() man page ... "The function is unsuccessful when there is not enough free heap space to create the mxArray."

try these flags for gcc -Wl,--heap=large_enough_value